# Create Normal Distribution (Bell Curve) chart using FLOT

Tags: charts, flot, normal-distribution

Has anyone tried creating Normal Distribution chart using FLOT?

If so, can you please put me in a right direction with some suggestions and links to tutorial?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FLOT is simply a plotting engine.  If you want to create a Bell Curve, you need to feed a probability density function a series of x values and plot the resulting points.

For instance I used the functions from [here](http://25yearsofprogramming.com/javascript/probability.js) to create this:

[image]

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tE24t/) that shows my work.

Comment: @DanielQuinn, I hope my link here didn't cause his webserver too much grief!

Comment: Also available in the Wayback Machine Internet archive : https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://25yearsofprogramming.com/javascript/probability.htm

Comment: Any idea how to shade a region between two lines on this bell curve (e.g. between -2 and 2)?

Comment: @Garry, if you want to fill under the curve, I'd create a second series that goes from -2 to 2 and set fill to `true`, if you want to fill the back ground from -2 to 2 use the markings option: https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid

Comment: [Here's another jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tE24t/290/) showing how you can highlight on the grid.