# Backgroud Bell Curve and show tooltips in Highchart charts

Tags: highcharts

I would like to show an arrow on bell shape curve. I know how to show the tooltip on dynamic chart, and I already have a bell curve. However, I have no idea about how to show the arrow on Bell curve.

Again, I made the bell curve from my data (x,y, sd, mean). and get the data from dynamic chart ans show the arrow on bell curve.

Bell Curve: [Create Normal Distribution (Bell Curve) chart using FLOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911151/create-normal-distribution-bell-curve-chart-using-flot)

Dynamic Chart: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/11-dynamic-charts-available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scatter serie with one point and customised marker

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter

or

use renderer to add image - like arrow - to the chart.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image()