# bell curve using flot

Tags: charts, flot, bell-curve

I have implemented a bell curve from the below link :
[Create Normal Distribution (Bell Curve) chart using FLOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911151/create-normal-distribution-bell-curve-chart-using-flot/7934045#7934045)

How to put the Lines on the Bell curve like the image :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911151/create-normal-distribution-bell-curve-chart-using-flot/7934045#comment41805232_7934045) in the question you linked, you can use markings to achieve this (see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tE24t/327/)):

[image: bell curve with markings]

The relevant code:

```
var markings = [];
for (var i= -2; i <= 2; i+= 1) {
    markings.push({ xaxis: { from: i, to: i }, yaxis: { from: 0, to: NormalDensityZx(i,0,1) }, color: "#bb0000" });
}
```

Comment: @Raidri- it helped.  Here's a fiddle to have it compare a specific marking with rest bell curve datapoints. http://jsfiddle.net/Lsm1086m/1/